# Directus api and app on same server as front-end

Tags: apache, rest, vue.js, directus

I'm attempting to create a small website using Directus as a back end, since it has a nice interface for managing a database. The front end will be coded in VueJS, and I'd like them both on the same site. I'm using Apache. For example:

www.example.com = VueJS frontend that pulls information from the Directus backend

www.example.com/admin = Directus admin link

www.example.com/api/[whatever] = RESTful api access

I've messed around with virtualhosts a bit but I can only move the entire directus app to a different port, which I don't want to do since I don't want admins to have to type the port number in manually if they want to access the example.com/admin interface.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can put the API on sub-domain like api.example.com that way both will be available on the same server.

I am just starting with the Directus and met with the same issue of putting both components and thought to put as written above.

If you followed some other approach, pls post here so that it can help people like me.

Comment: Look into Traefik path based routing, you can do this quite easily - https://blog.sethcorker.com/traefik-routing-for-web-apps/

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small mixin library for **Vue.JS 3** and **Directus API** that makes it easier for developers to make API calls quicker and with almost no code needed.

It supports **fetchCollection**, **fetchBtId**, **Sort**, **Filter** and **Search API** endpoints.

Check it out. Hope it helps anybody in the future.

https://github.com/Slaveworx/api-rabbit

Answer (score 0):

Here is a docker-compose config that implemented Traefik path based routing for another app. I haven't tested, but adapted it for Directus. Note HOST,ACME_EMAIL,TRAEFIK_BASICAUTH is configured in an .env file.

The real solution is in the [stripprefix middleware of Traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/stripprefix/)

This is an example of a `docker-compose.override.yaml`, I assume you already have a `docker-compose.yaml` with corresponding services:

```
version: "3"

services:
  directus:
    environment:
      PUBLIC_URL: https://${HOST}/api
    labels:
      traefik.enable: "true"
      # DIRECTUS API
      traefik.http.routers.directus-api.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.directus-api.rule: Host(`${HOST}`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)
      traefik.http.routers.directus-api.tls: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.directus-api.tls.certresolver: tls
      traefik.http.services.directus-api.loadbalancer.server.port: 8055
      traefik.http.middlewares.directus-api-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes: /api
      traefik.http.routers.directus-api.middlewares: directus-api-stripprefix
      # DIRECTUS ADMIN
      traefik.http.routers.directus-admin.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.directus-admin.rule: Host(`${HOST}`) && PathPrefix(`/admin`)
      traefik.http.routers.directus-admin.tls: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.directus-admin.tls.certresolver: tls
      traefik.http.services.directus-admin.loadbalancer.server.port: 8055

  vue-frontend:
    build:
      args:
        VITE_APP_BASE_URI: https://${HOST}
        VITE_API_BASE_URI: https://${HOST}/api
    labels:
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.react-admin.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.react-admin.rule: Host(`${HOST}`)
      traefik.http.routers.react-admin.tls: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.react-admin.tls.certresolver: tls
      traefik.http.services.react-admin.loadbalancer.server.port: 80

  traefik:
    command:
      - --accessLog=true
      - --api.insecure=false
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --api.debug=false
      - --certificatesresolvers.tls.acme.tlschallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.tls.acme.email=${ACME_EMAIL}
      - --certificatesresolvers.tls.acme.storage=/acme/acme.json
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true
      - --log.level=ERROR
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=my_net
    image: traefik:2.9
    labels:
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users: ${TRAEFIK_BASICAUTH}
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares: traefik-auth
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule: Host(`traefik.${HOST}`)
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.service: api@internal
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver: tls
      traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port: 8080
    networks:
      my_net: {}
    ports:
      - published: 80
        target: 80
      - published: 443
        target: 443
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/myapp/acme:/acme:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
```

You can check the traefik docs to understand how to configure values for `traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users` and more info on the docs. Traefik is useful for me because all config is minimal and in docker-compose configs, and traefik works in docker containers without needing much on the host.